# How to read variables from .env file using pydantic?

Tags: pydantic, validationerror, .env

I am trying to read variables from .env file, that looks like this:

```
A = 'aaa'
B = 'bbb'
```

To read variables I create Settings() class in test_vars.py:

```
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings, SettingsConfigDict


class Settings(BaseSettings):
    a: str
    b: str

    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(env_file='.env', env_file_encoding='utf-8')


config = Settings()
```

These two files are in the same directory.

When trying to create Settings() class, I get this error:

```
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 2 validation errors for Settings
a
  Field required [type=missing, input_value={}, input_type=dict]
```

Probably I should edit .env somehow, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code works fine.

When you run this code it will look for the `.env` file in the current working directory. So, you should run this code from the directory, where your `.env` file is placed. Or you can specify correct path to the `env` file from your working directory.

Comment: Thank You so much! Changing working directory helped.